# Perl process reaching 30MB and stuck

Tags: java, perl

I have a Perl script that is started by a Java process. When the process reaches 30MB it is stuck forever. I noticed that less then 27MB the script finished successfully.

My Java `-Xmx` and `-Xms` are 1500MB

The OS is Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit with 4G RAM.

I am using ActivePerl 5.18.4

Is there a limitation on memory of Perl process?

Comment: Please use *markdown* to format your questions. It will help you to read [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Is your perl executable built for 64-bit addressing? Check the output from `perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{ptrsize} * 8'` if you're not sure

Comment: I found the problem in the script. Either way, I don't know why users here decreased my question... :(

Answer (score 4):

No, Perl does not impose limit on how much memory the program can allocate.

The architecture imposes limits (32-bit processes have 2GB to 3GB of addressable memory), and the system can impose further limit (e.g. using `ulimit`), but that's not the issue here because Perl dies when it runs out of memory.

Your program blocked for reasons unrelated to the amount of memory it was using at the time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ikegami. I already figure it out.
I found the problem in my script. I was using warnings there and got lots of warnings which probably overflow the error stream and stuck the script while I was waiting in my Java code on the read() of the inputstream.